# Need steps to fasten the "ng serve" command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I run my angular project with
ng serve --disable-host-check
and it took ages to finish the complete the build. It's also the pain in my as* and lots of time spent to save my code and see the changes. I am not sure if it's because of many packages were installed. Here is the result and my package (mostly in use for my project)

How can i reduce the build time? It's now taking **40secs**

> ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
>
> Initial Chunk Files   | Names              |      Size vendor.js
> | vendor             |  11.19 MB main.js               | main
> |   2.22 MB styles.css            | styles             | 269.82 kB
> runtime.js            | runtime            |   9.11 kB
>
> Lazy Chunk Files      | Names              |      Size
> firebase-functions.js | firebase-functions |  25.48 kB
>
> 8 unchanged chunks
>
> Build at: 2021-05-03T13:20:58.420Z - Hash: bc9cf46c89c2c1d66cbc -
> Time: 40836ms

package.json

```
{
  "name": "airworkz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.2",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^2.1.5",
    "@firebase/logger": "^0.2.6",
    "@firebase/util": "^0.3.4",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.1.0",
    "and": "^0.0.3",
    "cache": "^2.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "clean": "^4.0.2",
    "compressorjs": "^1.0.7",
    "countries-list": "^2.6.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^8.2.6",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.3.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.0",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^7.0.1",
    "npm": "^7.6.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.2.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1200",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: leave the compiler running... It will auto-update to show you your changes

Answer (score 0):

I have 99% that the problem can be the packages, main the JSPDF that its size is 14.5MB according to the npm in this link: [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

Generally, packages that convert and visualize something in pdf, word, and other extensions have big size

If you want to resolve this problem, bring these functions to the backend server